# Seeing if a set is Countable or Not

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I have two sets: $\{x \in \mathbb N  \mid |x|  \le 600\}$ and $\{ x \in \mathbb R \mid x^2 -5x+6 \le 0\}$.

I said the first set is countably infinite because we can only get to $-600$ to $600$ and this set is countable.

The second set is uncountably infinite because $x\in \mathbb R$ and since $x$ is in a uncountable set this has to be uncountable.

I don't really get the countable\uncountable infinites so well. I know if a set $A \in \mathbb R$ it is uncountable, and if $A \in \mathbb N \lor \mathbb Q \lor \mathbb Z$ it is countable. If someone could confirm or see errors and point them out would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: My fault. I forgot to put that in. It's fixed now.

Comment: Your reasoning for the second set is incorrect. For example, the set $\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid x^2=2\}$ is finite, even though the definition includes $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Or consider $\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x^2+1\leq 0\}$, which is empty.

Comment: A hint for the second set: Any interval $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, with $a<b$, is uncountable.

Comment: So it's uncountable because the number between two intervals is uncountable because of the decimal points idea, right?

Comment: I think by "decimal points idea" you mean the diagonalization argument for uncountablility of $(0,1)$? If so, then yes the idea is the same. You can also construct an explicit bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first set is finite. It contains $1201$ elements, namely all integer numbers between $-600$ and $600$. For the second set note that $x^2-5x+6=(x-\frac{5}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$. Hence we have $x^2-5x+6\leq0\iff x\in[2,3]$ and every interval is uncountable.

Comment: When did $-600$ become a natural number?